# Difference between Shopify partner and Shopify admin

Tags: shopify

1.What is the major difference between Shopify partner and Shopify admin?
2.How to connect both?
3.Reason behind 2nd question is
only in partner site we can see the status of API health and
I can only see order/customer/product details in Shopify admin not in partner. In my use case I want to see order/customer/product details and also want to test GDPR webhooks. How it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

A partner account can be created on https://en.shopify.hk/partners. When you create a Shopify Partners account, you gain access to a Partners dashboard, and you will become a *Shopify Partner*. By creating a partner account, you would become an **admin of the partner account** will be able to:

1. **Create Development Stores**: those are stores that you can create for free and use them to develop new Shopify themes, apps etc. Development stores do not have a monthly recurring hosting fees. However, they are password protected, and cannot accept any form of payments as the purpose is to either develop and/or test themes and apps. After setting up a development store, you can also change it to a **Managed Store** by transferring ownership of the store to a client who will then pay for the hosting, and make the store functional. This client will then become the **admin** of the store.
2. **Create Managed Stores**: those are stores that you create to sell; you pay a monthly hosting fees depending on the pricing plan you select, and users will be able to make payments through those stores.
3. **Develop public/custom/private apps.**
4. **Link to specific stores**: if you want to update the code on another merchant's store, which you did not create, you can click link the store by adding a **Managed Store**, then input their store URL, and send them a **Collaborator Access Request**. Upon accepting your request, their store would appear in your partner dashboard and you can access their store dashboard to see orders, customers etc. On the list of stores in the partner dashboard, you will see a **Log In** link to login to the dashboard of each store individually.
5. **Add members**: you can add members to your Partner Dashboard and give them different roles, and access to specific stores linked to your partner account. This way, if you want multiple developers to work on a store you have access to, they can access those stores (although the store owner will not know who is accessing, they would only know that it's being accessed by your partner account specifically).

For each store linked to your partner account, you will see whether it is a Development Store, or if it's a Managed Store, you will see the plan chosen. For Managed Stores, you can also click on **Actions** and completely **Remove access** for yourself by unlinking your partner account from the store.

[image]

On the other hand, a Shopify admin account refers to an administrator account specific to a store. For example, if you *own* a store, you would be the store admin. Each store can only have one admin, and a selected number of staffs. The Basic Shopify plan can only have two staffs. However, each store can have *unlimited collaborators* which mean, each store can be linked to multiple Partner accounts. Partner accounts only gain access to what the store administrator provides them access with. When you send them a collaborator request, it asks you if you would like to request access to everything, or only specific parts of the store, such as themes/apps only.

Comment: Only in shopify partner I can see the status of webhook and API health.  I want to see order/customer/product details and also want to test GDPR webhooks. How it is possible?

Comment: Is it possible to use Admin API without using Shopify Partner? I am already an admin of Shopify Plus store.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify partner is platform for developers/users where they can handle multiple stores at the same time. Where they can see their development or managed stores. But When it comes to Shopify admin is related to specific store where you can see products , orders , themes and many other things of the store. Thanks